# Testing an execute() method using mocking for JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I have a method that executes a SQL statement using statement.execute(query). How to test this void function as it returns nothing? I am using Mockito and using @Spy.

Have attached my code snippet for my execute() method, which takes in a ArrayList of queries:

```
public void execute(Statement statement, ArrayList<String> queryList) throws SQLException {
        SQLException sqlException = null;
        // read script line by line
        for (String line : queryList) {
            try {
                statement.execute(line);
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                if (null == sqlException)
                    sqlException = e1;
                else {``
                    sqlException.addSuppressed(e1);
                }
            }
        }
        if (null != sqlException)
            throw sqlException;
    }
```

This is my test class that I need to use for testing the void execute() method in my main class. I am using Mocking and doNothing() but I am getting Unnecessary Stubbing Exception.

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class TestSQL {

    @Spy
    RunSQL runSQL=new RunSQL("dbConfig");
    @Mock
    BufferedReader br;
    @Spy
    ArrayList<String> queryList;
    @Mock
    Statement s;
    @Mock
    Connection c;
    @Mock
    RunSQL runsql;
    @Test
    public void testExecute() throws SQLException, IOException {
        Mockito.when(br.readLine()).thenReturn("something");
        runSQL.execute(s, queryList);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(runsql).execute(s,queryList);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you also share the exception log?

Answer (score 0):

The regular execution path can be tested like the following:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class RunSQLTest {
    @Test
    public void queries_are_executed_one_by_one() throws SQLException {
        //given:
        RunSQL runSQL = new RunSQL("dbConfig");
        List<String> queries = new ArrayList<>();
        queries.add("query1");
        queries.add("query2");
        Statement statement = mock(Statement.class);

        //when:
        runSQL.execute(statement, queries);

        //then:
        verify(statement, times(1)).execute("query1");
        verify(statement, times(1)).execute("query2");
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(statement);
    }
}
```

Here you just strictly assert that all your queries are being executed successfully one-by-one without any exception thrown. Strictness is achieved by adding `verifyNoMoreInteractions(statement)`. If you don't add this then Mockito just does its best to stub mock interactions. It's the default behaviour